# Beta decay and interaction Hamiltonian in nuclei

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

I just started studying the theory of beta decay and I can't really understand the whole concept of an interaction Hamiltonian. If the nucleons are inside the nucleus the "beta decay" interaction Hamiltonian $V = g\delta(\bf{r}-\bf{r}')$ should be accounted for in the total Hamiltonian.

This means that if the nucleus has a definite energy the nucleons should be in an eigen state of the total Hamiltonian $H_{tot} = H_{nucl} + V$. How can they decay then? Why am I allowed to treat $V$ as an external perturbation when it really isn't?

Comment: "...if the nucleus has a definite energy..." It doesn't. It almost does, but not quite. That's exactly why it can decay. Are you studying a source that says the nucleus starts with a definite energy? If so, then does the context suggest that the word "energy" refers to $H_\text{nucl}$ instead of to the more physically-meaningful $H_\text{tot}$?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly It doesn't say anything about energy I just assumed it had a definite energy because I'm so used with working with energy eigenstate. What you say makes a lot of sense. My only doubt then is why does it start in an approximate eigenstate of the total energy (and now I get that the word approximate is important)? Does it just happen that through all the interactions with the external environment (which can be regarded as some kind of measurement of position, energy and velocity) the nucleus ends up in an almost exact energy eigenstate and from there it decays? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, what you said is essentially correct. Whatever process produced the nucleus in the first place did not produce it in an eigenstate of the total energy. Eventually, in otherwise empty space, we would end up with only stable particles drifting away from each other, and that still isn't an energy eigenstate -- because in order for the decay products to be in separate locations, they must be localized to some degree, and energy eigenstates don't have that property.